# is there a way i can fix my accordion in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and I tried to make an accordion component, and it' didn't work like I wanted it to, here's my html code.

```
 <div class="faq-item-container">
      <h1 class="mt-1 mb-5"><strong>Frequently Aksed Questions</strong></h1>
    <div class="row" (click)="toggleDetail(); toggleIcon();" *ngFor= "let faq of faqs">
      <div class="col my-2">
        <h3> {{faq.title}} <a><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown" class="float-right"></fa-icon></a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12" *ngIf="showDetail">
        <div class="faq-detail-container mt-1">
          <div class="col-12">
            <p><small>
              {{faq.content}}
            </small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's the ts code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {faChevronUp, faChevronDown, IconDefinition, faSquare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobs-faq',
  templateUrl: './jobs-faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobs-faq.component.scss']
})
export class JobsFaqComponent implements OnInit {
  faChevronUp: IconDefinition = faChevronUp;
  faChevronDown: IconDefinition = faChevronDown;


  showDetail: boolean;
  faqs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'faq1',
      content: 'content1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'faq2',
      content: 'content2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'faq3',
      content: 'content3'
    }
  ];


  constructor() {
    this.showDetail = false;
   }


  toggleDetail(): void {
    this.showDetail = !this.showDetail;
  }
  toggleIcon() {
    if (this.faChevronDown === faChevronDown) {
        this.faChevronDown = faChevronUp;
    } else {
        this.faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
    }
}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The problem is when I click faq1, the others also collpasing, yes I know it's because I called the same function, and that is what I want to ask about, how to call the function separately to make this accordion working like it's supposed to be? thanks.

Comment: couldn't check your code but i would recomend you use accordion from angular material. https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Comment: i don't want to use to many css frameworks because i wanna learn from the basic:(

Comment: @sooyoungie, you has severals "faqs", so you need severals "variables". The easy way is that the variable was a propertie of the "faq" -equals happens with the "icons". So, pass as argument to the functions toggle the own object "faq" (using `(click)="toggle(faq)"` and use faq.showDetail and faq.faChevronDown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to close all other sections when you click one or not, but a solution could look somewhat like this:

```html
<div class="faq-item-container">
      <h1 class="mt-1 mb-5"><strong>Frequently Aksed Questions</strong></h1>
    <div class="row" (click)="toggleDetail(faq.id); toggleIcon();" *ngFor= "let faq of faqs">
      <div class="col my-2">
        <h3> {{faq.title}} <a><fa-icon [icon]="faChevronDown" class="float-right"></fa-icon></a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12" *ngIf="faq.showDetail">
        <div class="faq-detail-container mt-1">
          <div class="col-12">
            <p><small>
              {{faq.content}}
            </small></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {faChevronUp, faChevronDown, IconDefinition, faSquare} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobs-faq',
  templateUrl: './jobs-faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobs-faq.component.scss']
})
export class JobsFaqComponent implements OnInit {
  faChevronUp: IconDefinition = faChevronUp;
  faChevronDown: IconDefinition = faChevronDown;

  faqs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'faq1',
      content: 'content1',
      showDetail: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'faq2',
      content: 'content2',
      showDetail: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'faq3',
      content: 'content3',
      showDetail: false
    }
  ];

  toggleDetail(faqId: number): void {
    this.faqs = this.faqs.map(faq => {
        faq.showDetail = (faq.id == faqId) ? !faq.showDetail : false;
        return faq;
    });
  }

  toggleIcon() {
    if (this.faChevronDown === faChevronDown) {
        this.faChevronDown = faChevronUp;
    } else {
        this.faChevronDown = faChevronDown;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Note that your [icon]="faChevronDown" should be based on the faq in the thes scope of your *ngFor. I'll leave it to you as practice to find a solution for that. (Hint: you could use a ternary operation based on faq.showDetail)

Comment: to be honest i want the behaviour is to be when you click one faq, it expands and the others closed, any way i can achieve something like that?

Comment: See edit (you should really try to do it yourself first when a comment is left for you to do it, that's how you learn it best ;) ).